# +/- icon jQuery Sub-Accordion (Parent & Children Elements)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have created the following jQuery Accordion with parent and children elements:

**jQuery:**

```
/* Accordion with +/- icon */

/* Parent Elements */

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".accordion_parent").accordion({
    collapsible: true,
    active: false,
    animate: 500,
  }).on("click", "div", function(e) {
    $("div.ui-accordion_parent-header").each(function(i, el) {
      if ($(this).is(".ui-state-active")) {
        $(this).find(".panel-icon").html("-")
      } else {
        $(this).find(".panel-icon").html("+")
      }
    })
  });

});


/* Children Elements */

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".accordion_child").accordion({
        collapsible: true,
        active: false,
        animate: 500,
      }).on("click", "div", function(e) {
        $("div.ui-accordion_child-header").each(function(i, el) {
          if ($(this).is(".ui-state-active")) {
            $(this).find(".panel-icon").html("-")
          } else {
            $(this).find(".panel-icon").html("+")
          }
        })
      });

    });
```

In the JSFiddle in the comment you can see the entire code including HTML and CSS. 
The jQuery as well as the HTML and CSS code is divided in a code for the parent and children elements. 
After I included the children elements into the accordion the +/- icon does not work anymore. It is probably an issue with the line ("div.ui-accordion_parent-header") and ("div.ui-accodrion_children-header") in the jQuery code. How can I make the +/- icons work both for the parent and the children elements?

Comment: Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ypv8yow1/20/

Comment: Looks like its working wheres the problem

Comment: When I click on the parent element the children elements open but the + sign does not change to a - sign. Same applies to the children elements. When I open them and the content appears the + sign does not change to a - sign.

Comment: here is simple accordion without jquery ui i have use .slideToggle(), for `+` and `-` i have used `:pseudo` class http://jsfiddle.net/ypv8yow1/21/

Comment: Man, this is so great and simple. Thank you a lot :-) If you enter your solution as an answer I can click the check-sign and you can get some points.

Comment: your welcome :) added it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the simple solution for creating a accordion

[js-fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ypv8yow1/21/)

- used [.slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) for sliding
- used pseudo class for adding `+` and `-` sign as per the class

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".js_button_parent").on('click', function() {
    $(this).next('.panel_parent').slideToggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.accordion_parent {
  float: left;
  line-height: 2.0;
  width: 100%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-left-width: 1px;
  border-right-width: 1px;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  margin-top: 1%;
}
.js_button_parent {
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 1%;
  font-weight: bold;
  outline-width: 0;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.js_button_parent:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -1px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 1px;
  background: #000;
}
.panel_parent {
  width: 99%;
  padding-left: 1%;
  font-weight: bold;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: none;
}
/* Accordion Children */

.accordion_child {
  float: left;
  line-height: 2.0;
  width: 99%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-left-width: 1px;
  border-right-width: 1px;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  margin-top: 1%;
}
.js_button_child {
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 1%;
  font-weight: bold;
  outline-width: 0;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.js_button_parent:before {
  content: '+';
  width: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.js_button_parent.active:before {
  content: '-';
}
.js_button_child:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -1px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 1px;
  background: #000;
}
.panel_child {
  width: 99%;
  padding-left: 1%;
  font-weight: bold;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.panel-icon {
  float: left;
  width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion_parent">
  <div class="js_button_parent">Parent1</div>
  <div class="panel_parent">
    <div class="accordion_parent">
      <div class="js_button_parent">Child1</div>
      <div class="panel_parent">
        <p>Child1 Content</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion_child">
      <div class="js_button_parent">Child2</div>
      <div class="panel_parent">
        <p>Child2 Content</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion_parent">
  <div class="js_button_parent">Parent2</div>
  <div class="panel_parent">
    <p>Parent2 Content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```